# mvc - allow asp tags in chtml pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there anyway to allow asp tags in chtml MVC pages? Do I have to declare something in the view itself? I know its possible to have an aspx page in the solution, but I would like to combine controls in the chtml page.

Example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<asp:calander>...

etc
```

Comment: Learn jQuery.  You'll thank yourself later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Razor does not support WebForm controls, but you need to see Scott Hanselman's example if you really want to mix n match

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx